# Subscribe simultaneously but emit in order?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Is there a way to take a collection of Observables, subscribe to them all at once, but have them emit in a certain order?

My use case is that I want to make several HTTP requests and have them going at the same time because the requests are independant of one another. However, I need one of those HTTP requests to have their result be assigned to a variable only *after* all of the other requests have finished their result actions.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let $prereqs: Observable<any>[] = [];

$prereqs.push(
    this.doThing1().map(results => {
        this.thing1Variable = results;
    })
);
$prereqs.push(
    this.doThing2().map(results => {
        this.thing2Variable = results;
    })
);
$prereqs.push(
    this.doThingLast().map(results => {
        this.lastVariable = results;
    })
);

// ...Subscribe to all of them at once HERE...
```

I thought this might be nicer than `forkJoin` because then I don't need to keep track of the index I want from the final Observable result and instead I could just subscribe them all at once and let them execute their `map` actions.

I am open to approaching this a different way too.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: @JBNizet it looks like `forkJoin` would only solve the first issue which is subscribing them all at once. But in my example case at least it doesn't guarentee that `this.lastVariable = results;` will be called only after the other two observables have omitted (and assigned `thing1Variable` and `thing2Variable` respectively)

Comment: Yes, it would, because if the resulting observable emits, it means all the initial observables have completed, and have thus already emitted and invoked their map() (which should be do()).

Comment: @JBNizet oh so `forkJoin` forces all the observables to emit in order even if they finish out of the provided order?

Comment: No. forkJoin emits once. And it emits an array containing the last value emitted by each of the observables. The first element of the array is the last value emitted by the first observable, the second element is the last value emitted by the second observable, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, that's not actually what I'm trying to do then. I know I could do that but I don't want to have to pull the value emitted by `doThingLast` out of that array as I explained in my question (although I incorrectly mentioned `zip` where I should have said `forkJoin`)

Comment: And why wouldn't you want to do that? It's one trivial line of code.

Comment: @JBNizet am I incorrect in assuming that if someone added another push before then it would change the index of the value I want to get? I could see that causing a bug later on

Comment: It would still be the last index of the array. But that is irrelevant. If someone deleted the code, it wouldn't do the same thing either. That's why you write readable code, comments, and automated tests: to prevent regressions.

Comment: For future reference, on the very main page of rxjs there's a little questionnaire that helps you find operators. It's really really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" approach definitely is

```
Observable.forkJoin(obs1$, obs2$)
  .subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
    this.thing1 = result1;
    this.thing2 = result2;
 });
```

As a side note, you're misusing `map` in your question. That's an operator to transform emitted values. You're performing a side effect, which is what `do` is for.

Comment: I see I was using `map` to get back an observable so I could subscribe to it later but define the side effect right away. Thank you for the example code now I understand why `forkJoin` would be a better solution. My original idea depended on my misuse of `map` essentially.

Comment: `do` also returns an observable. It returns its source observable unchanged. With `map` (the way you were using it) you're actually returning an observable stripped of its values (not its emissions, just the emissions have undefined values).

Comment: Oh okay I see. So even if I used `do` and wanted a side-effect would it still be better to just move all that side effect logic into the forkJoin? I guess it would depend on if I wanted to load some data into the UI that had no dependencies first while waiting for them all to finish to load `lastVariable`

Comment: The do operator *is* the side effect. Once you move something into the subscribe handler of, say, the forkJoin, it's no longer a side effect.